# Whats the problem with this preg_match script?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Why does this code not give me any results?

```
if(preg_match('#referer\.php\?url=(.*?)#s',$result,$array2)) { 
    echo $array2[1]; 
}
```

The thing is, if I change `echo $array2[1]` to `echo "test";` it will show me `test`. So the problem doesnt seem to be the `preg_match` algorithm, does it? What could be the problem?

I want to have the url, which is written after the `url=`, for example `referer.php?url=http://www.example.com` should give `http://www.example.com` as result in the `$array2`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: are you sure $result has the right content to match? echo it out?

Comment: Yes, $result is a long HTML with something like this in it:
`href="/referer.php?url=http://www.example.com">`

Comment: I'm not convinced. There's no reason your pattern wouldn't match that, which means $result must not contain the content you expect.

Comment: But if it wouldnt contain the content I expected, then how come that echo "test"; will gime me an output allthough I am using a if-clause?

Comment: hmm..for your pattern, try '#referer\.php\?url=([^\'"]*)#s'

Comment: @Crayon Violent... Thank you! Working perfectly! But will this also work if URL is completely different (without numbers at the end)?

Comment: yes. it is a negative character class, matching anything that is not a single or double quote

Comment: Allright, thank you! I will never get these regex expression, they are so complicated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your input is: `<td align="center" width="90%"><b><a target="_blank" href="/referer.php?url=http://www.example.com?somethin=1234">Go to this homepage</a></b>`

and you want `http://www.example.com?somethin=1234`,

Your regex would look like this:

`/referer\.php\?url=([^"]*)`

That would make your php look like this:

```
if(preg_match('#/referer\.php\?url=([^"]*)#',$result,$array2)){ 
    print_r($array2);
}
```

Comment: Your url will be at: `$array2[1]`

Answer (score 1):

try changing it this way:

```
if(preg_match('#referer\.php\?url=(.*)$#s',$result,$array2))
```

so `print_r($array2)` will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => referer.php?url=http://www.example.com
    [1] => http://www.example.com
)
```

that is the result you want. Hope it helps!

Comment: all that will do is change the quantifier from lazy to greedy and since it's the last part of the pattern, $ is pointless. IOW this will in no way solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, allready better. Now it shows the URL but it also shows everything that is behind the URL. So as output I got all the HTML code starting at `http://www.example.com`. I need to make a cut after the URL since I only want the URL.

Comment: @phpeini what else do you have after the url? Could you post the full query string please? Do you have some other get params?

Comment: @Crayon Violent... you should test before posting and downvoting. Lazy matching will make the expression useless, since it will skip matching the last part completely. Do some homework before downvoting

Comment: Ok, so this would be the HTML around the URL: `<td align="center" width="90%"><b><a target="_blank" href="/referer.php?url=http://www.example.com?somethin=1234">Go to this homepage</a></b>`
And then there is alot more HTML following. So now the output is: `http://www.example.com?somethin=1234">Go to this homepage</a></b> and so on...` No other get params.

Comment: fair enough, I'll give you point back if you edit your content (timed out)

Comment: @phpeini do you need match everthing included =1234 and then stop?

Comment: @Crayon Violent, nevermind for the vote and thank you for responding

Comment: @Ass3mbler... Yes everything until the "
But the URL is allways different, not allways ending with numbers!

Comment: @phpeini ok then: if(preg_match('#referer\.php\?url=(.*)\"$#s',$result,$array2))